# How I specify sonar scanner to pick up a particular quality profile I have downloaded as an xml?

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

The quality profile on sonar server and local sonar server are different, I've downloaded the XML from sonar server and I want to specify to pick up that particular quality profile, where do I configure this?

I do not have admin access to server to be able to configure anything.

```
$ ./sonar-analysis.sh
INFO: Scanner configuration file: C:\localAnalysis\sonar-scanner-3.0.3.778\conf\sonar-scanner.properties
INFO: Project root configuration file: C:\IBM\aatman-mdmapp\tools\localAnalysis\sonar-project-mdm.properties
INFO: SonarQube Scanner 3.0.3.778
INFO: Java 1.8.0_121 Oracle Corporation (64-bit)
INFO: Windows 7 6.1 amd64
INFO: SONAR_SCANNER_OPTS=-Xmx1024m
INFO: User cache: C:\Users\kothara\.sonar\cache
INFO: Publish mode
INFO: Load global settings
INFO: Load global settings (done) | time=319ms
INFO: Server id: 15323a874858ec5
INFO: User cache: C:\Users\kothara\.sonar\cache
INFO: Load plugins index
INFO: Load plugins index (done) | time=156ms
INFO: Load/download plugins
INFO: Load/download plugins (done) | time=3403ms
INFO: SonarQube server 7.1.0
INFO: Default locale: "en_GB", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
INFO: Process project properties
INFO: Execute project builders
INFO: Execute project builders (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Load project branches
INFO: Load project branches (done) | time=63ms
INFO: Load project pull requests
INFO: Load project pull requests (done) | time=40ms
INFO: Load branch configuration
INFO: Load branch configuration (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Load project repositories
INFO: Load project repositories (done) | time=559ms
INFO: Load quality profiles
INFO: Load quality profiles (done) | time=77ms
INFO: Load active rules
INFO: Load active rules (done) | time=2360ms
INFO: Load metrics repository
INFO: Load metrics repository (done) | time=103ms
INFO: Project key: SVOC:MDMApp:MDM:WS057562-kothara-Local
INFO: Project base dir: C:\IBM\aatman-mdmapp
INFO: -------------  Scan SVOC:MDMApp:MDM:WS057562-kothara-Local
INFO: Base dir: C:\IBM\aatman-mdmapp
INFO: Working dir: c:\localAnalysis\working\sonar\MDM
INFO: Source paths: Aviva/Source/WAS/MDMApp/AvivaBusinessProxyComposites, Aviva/Source/WAS/MDMApp/AvivaBusinessProxyCompositesWS
INFO: Source encoding: UTF-8, default locale: en_GB
INFO: Load server rules
INFO: Load server rules (done) | time=515ms
WARN: Property 'sonar.abap.file.suffixes' is not declared as multi-values/property set but was read using 'getStringArray' method. The SonarQube plugin declaring this property should be updated.
INFO: Index files
INFO: Included sources:
INFO:   **/src/**/*.java
INFO:   **/ejbModule/**/*.java
INFO: Excluded sources:
INFO:   **/to/**.java
INFO: 393 files indexed
INFO: 3111 files ignored because of inclusion/exclusion patterns
INFO: Quality profile for java: Sonar way
INFO: Sensor JavaSquidSensor [java]
INFO: Configured Java source version (sonar.java.source): 6
INFO: JavaClasspath initialization
WARN: Bytecode of dependencies was not provided for analysis of source files, you might end up with less precise results. Bytecode can be provided using sonar.java.libraries property
INFO: JavaClasspath initialization (done) | time=8ms
INFO: JavaTestClasspath initialization
INFO: JavaTestClasspath initialization (done) | time=1ms
INFO: Java Main Files AST scan
INFO: 393 source files to be analyzed
```

Answer (score 0):

**You must be an administrator to be able to make this change.**
[image]
[image]

1. Go to Administration > Quality Profile.
2. From the drop-down beside the language, choose your custom quality profile.

---

### Note: This option won't be visible if you do not have the admin rights.